# How can I enable OkHttp's MockWebServer logging?

Tags: java, android, logging, okhttp, mockwebserver

I was using an old version of MockWebServer 3.14.9 in my Android project and I could see its logs in the logcat when running my UI Tests. After updating to the latest 4.10.0 I can't see any MockWebServer logs for requests and responses. It appears that the logging level was changed from INFO to FINE in [this PR](https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/5696/files). As you can see in the [latest code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/mockwebserver/src/main/kotlin/mockwebserver3/MockWebServer.kt#L642), that hasn't changed.

```kotlin
if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
    logger.fine(
      "${this@MockWebServer} received request: $request and responded: $response"
    )
  }
```

I tried debugging it and found that `if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE))` always returns false.

Here's the code for `Logger.isLoggable` ([source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/e68024c2d28d634ebfde7f2fdcc35f5d7b07d704/src/java.logging/share/classes/java/util/logging/Logger.java#L2035)):

```java
/**
* Check if a message of the given level would actually be logged
* by this logger.  This check is based on the Loggers effective level,
* which may be inherited from its parent.
*
* @param   level   a message logging level
* @return  true if the given message level is currently being logged.
*/
public boolean isLoggable(Level level) {
    int levelValue = config.levelValue;
    if (level.intValue() < levelValue || levelValue == offValue) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So by putting a breakpoint in this method I could see that it returns false because the requested level `FINE` (defined as **500** [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/e68024c2d28d634ebfde7f2fdcc35f5d7b07d704/src/java.logging/share/classes/java/util/logging/Level.java#L179)), is apparently lower than the Logger's level `INFO` (defined as **800** [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/e68024c2d28d634ebfde7f2fdcc35f5d7b07d704/src/java.logging/share/classes/java/util/logging/Level.java#L146)).

**So was the aforementioned PR to change the level to `FINE` incorrect as it didn't consider that the Logger was still created with level `INFO` which is higher?**

**Or is there something I'm missing and there is a way to change the Logger level or otherwise see the logs from MockWebServer?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste the configuration from the debug logging doc here:
https://square.github.io/okhttp/contribute/debug_logging/

```
OkHttpDebugLogging.enable(MockWebServer::class)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried that but I only see one log 

`MockWebServer[8080] starting to accept connections` at the Warn level and the tag `System.err`. I'm using MockWebServer in Android UI Tests by the way if that makes any difference (I've added that to my question). Also, would you happen to know if this approach is the intended way for adopters of OkHttp to enable logging or is this a workaround?

Comment: From that page you linked I tried the command `adb shell setprop log.tag.okhttp.MockWebServer DEBUG` and that results in seeing 2 logs `MockWebServer[8080] received request: GET /v5/launches HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and `MockWebServer[8080] done accepting connections: Socket closed` but not the initial "starting to accept connections" log mentioned in my previous comment weirdly enough. Is there a way I can expand the logs in either case? I would like the logs to include the actual data sent and received like the headers & body.

Comment: If you want more logging, you might be able to accomplish something with a custom Dispatcher. But MockWebServer isn't really designed to have extensible logging in this way.